# how to match the lemma of a string with the lemmas of the list using phrase matcher in spacy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, matcher, lemmatization

I have a list and a sentence and I want to match the list with lemma of words in the sentence, i.e,

```
list_words = ['play', 'burn fireworks', 'eat']
sentence = "sita was playing with her friends while her broter was burning fireworks"
```

I tried,

```
patterns = [__model.make_doc(text) for text in list_words]
spacy_doc = __model(sentence)
matcher = PhraseMatcher(__model.vocab, attr="LEMMA")
mather.add(id, None, *patterns)
```

that is adding **LEMMA** as **attr** in PhraseMtcher,
but it did not help me
as it should have matched **burning fireworks** and playing from the sentence and instead of that, i am getting a empty list.

Answer (score 0):

If `__model` has the tagger enabled (which it probably does by default), this will work if you change `__model.make_doc(text)` to `__model(text)` when you create the patterns. `make_doc()` only works for `attr="ORTH"` because it doesn't do anything beyond tokenization.

If you have a lot of lemma-based patterns and none of them need parses or named entities, you could disable `parser` and `ner` in `__model` to make things faster, since the lemmatizer only depends on the tagger.

(`PhraseMatcher` warns you that `nlp(text)` might be slow for `ORTH`-only patterns and suggests using `nlp.make_doc()` instead, but I think it should also try to warn you if your document doesn't have the attributes you're trying to match.)